# Python split list into sublists if numbers are divided by a number of consecutive zeros

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

Hi I have the following list:

```
l = [1,2,4,6,0,5,0,0,0,6,17,0,0,7,0]
```

I want to have a list of lists where each sublist could be made by indexes or numbers themselves, the condition of the split is the presence of at least 2 consecutive 0s.
Here the result:

```
[[1,2,4,6,0,5],[6,17],[7,0]] # instead of the elements could be the indices
```

Do you have any solution?

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. I would suggest that you do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: @han solo  No, at least 2 consecutive 0, you always need to get all the 0s defining a split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools.groupby`

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import groupby

l = [1,2,4,6,0,5,0,0,0,6,7,0,0,7,0]
result = [[]]
for k, v in groupby(l):
    v = list(v)
    if k == 0 and len(v) > 1:
        result.append([])
    else:
        result[-1].extend(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 5], [6, 7], [7, 0]]
```

Comment: the number 1 is missing from your solution

Comment: Updated snippet

Comment: @Rakesh what will happen with `[1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2, 2]`?

Comment: @ReutSharabani. That's a very valid scenario. Thanks. Updated snippet.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only single digit numbers (thanks @3nomis), and you don't mind the overhead of converting to and from strings:

Create a string from the list:

```
l_str = ''.join(map(str, l))
```

> '124605000670070'

Split with a regular expression:

```
splits = re.split('0[0]+', l_str)
```

> ['124605', '67', '70']

Join again mapping back to integers:

```
from functools import partial
result = map(partial(map, int), splits)
```

> [[1, 2, 4, 6, 0, 5], [6, 7], [7, 0]]

Or as a single line (less recommended):

```
map(partial(map, int), re.split('0[0]+', ''.join(map(str, l))))
```

Comment: The problem with this is having 2 digits numbers